# how to open new window tab in html but is not working after using target="_blank" in mainnav?

Tags: javascript, html

In my menu bar if I put target="_blank"it's not opening a new page and nothing is happening. If I put it in another place it is working fine. If I use id there is no problem.  https://practical-engelbart-ed4790.netlify.com/

Comment: Please update your code over here, so that we can get the exact problem. [mcve]

Comment: there is no target="_blank" code in your site

Comment: you have given google play download link target='_blank' and it is opening in new window.

Answer (score 0):

`target="_blank"` always works in any of the conditions.  I guess, in your case there may any bunch of code in other JS file  which may be removing this attribute form the  menu link.

Do one thing,  go to  view source an check your  current menu  link is having this attribute with in it HTML or not. Try to remove other attributes one  by one and check which  one is  giving conflict with `target="_blank"`.